# How to change Magento Content-Type Charset in Newsletter

Tags: magento, character-encoding, newsletter

I got problems with special chars (Umlaute, €-Sign, ...) in my newsletter send from Magento (1.7.0.2). The Header looks like the following:

```
Received: (qmail 27694 invoked by uid 10018); 15 Dec 2013 12:18:31 +0100
Message-Id: <20131215111831.27691.qmail@********.de>
To: ***********
Subject: ********* Dezember 2013
X-Php-Originating-Script: 10018:Sendmail.php
From: ******
Date: Sun, 15 Dec 2013 11:18:31 +0000
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

I guess the Problem is the wrong charset... So how can i change the charset from iso-8859-1 to utf8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this in `\lib\PEAR\Mail\mime.php`, `\lib\Zend\Mail.php`.

Don't know if you have to change these files also:

```
\lib\PEAR\Mail\xmail.dtd

\lib\PEAR\Mail\xmail.xsl
```

Comment: Thanks! \lib\Zend\Mail.php was the solution.
Change protected $_charset = 'iso-8859-1';
to protected $_charset = 'utf-8';